# How to get the color of an element using angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

I am being try to get the color of an element using angular js, but am unsuccessful. Here is what I am doing:

```
function colorApply() {
 var cardsList = document.getElementsByClassName("card-abbr");
 $timeout(function() {
  angular.forEach(cardsList, function(value) {
   var color = value.css('color');
   /*var color = value.style.color;*/
   console.log(color);
  });
 }, 1000);
}
```

My CSS:

```
.card-abbr:nth-child(1n) {
    color: #EF2525;
}
.card-abbr:nth-child(2n) {
    color: #88ba41;
}
.card-abbr:nth-child(3n) {
    color: #850057;
}
.card-abbr:nth-child(4n) {
    color: #003f60;
}
.card-abbr:nth-child(5n) {
    color: #588ba3;
}
```

This is returning nothing for me.
Please help.

Comment: a fiddle will help us more faster.. :)

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: can you put your `html`  structure as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
function colorApply() {
  var cardsList = document.getElementsByClassName('card-abbr')
  angular.forEach(cardsList, function(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null)
    var color = style.getPropertyValue('color')
  })
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you :)